# Angular Modal issue

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a modal from 
https://plnkr.co/edit/VSOzZ8AJz61az9TANGsp?p=preview

However, I am trying to put the modal into a component instead of  directive as shown in the plunker above. I rant into one error ($.confirm)

```
import { Component, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, Directive, ElementRef, NgModule,Input } from '@angular/core';


import { Overlay } from 'ngx-modialog';
import { Modal } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';



@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'modal.component.html'

})
export class ModalComponent {
    closeResult: string;

    name: string;
    constructor(public modal: Modal) {
        this.name = 'Angular version'
    }

    @Output('confirm-click') click: any = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('click', ['$event']) clicked(e) {
        $.confirm({
            buttons: {
                confirm: () => this.click.emit(),
                cancel: () => { }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

error:  Cannot find name '$'.

************************************UPDATE**************************************

I just ended up using bootstrap Modal , which works and easy to implement
modal.html

```
<div>


    <span class="fa fa-trash-o"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

    </span>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Delete this record?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onOk()">OK</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal.ts

```
     import { Component, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, Directive, ElementRef, NgModule,Input } from '@angular/core';


import { Overlay } from 'ngx-modialog';
import { Modal } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';

declare const jQuery: {
    confirm: Function
};

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'modal.component.html'

})
export class ModalComponent {
    @Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


    onOk() {
        console.log("OK");
        this.open.emit('yes');
    }
    onDelete() {

        console.log("Cancel");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your Plunkr code is not the same as the above code. Can you update this please?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

or

```
declare const jQuery: {
  confirm: Function
};
```

and in your code

```
jQuery.confirm();
```

Comment: Thanks Fateh, that did get rid of the error, however, the page errored out due to my Jquery file does not contain the function "confirm" any ideas where/how I can get the file with such function?

Comment: where do I declare the Jquery function..I was unable to add it to my Jquery file? updated my above question

Comment: replace import * as $ from 'scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js'; with declare const jQuery: {
  confirm: Function
}; and then call jQuery.confirm

Comment: updated my code..I get 
error :jQuery.confirm is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try `modal.confirm()` instead of `$.confirm`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using bootstrap Modal , which works and easy to implement
modal.html

```
<div>


    <span class="fa fa-trash-o"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">

    </span>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Delete this record?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onOk()">OK</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Modal.ts

```
     import { Component, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter, Directive, ElementRef, NgModule,Input } from '@angular/core';


import { Overlay } from 'ngx-modialog';
import { Modal } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';

declare const jQuery: {
    confirm: Function
};

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'modal.component.html'

})
export class ModalComponent {
    @Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


    onOk() {
        console.log("OK");
        this.open.emit('yes');
    }
    onDelete() {

        console.log("Cancel");
    }

}
```